# Django Serializer POST data not fully passed to serializer

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have the following serializer definition:

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contexts = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = (
            "id",
            "contexts"
        )

    def get_contexts(self, obj):
       return ...

    def create(self, data):
        print('CREATE')
        print(data)
        return super().create(data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        print('UPDATE')
        print(validated_data)
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

and in a viewset the usage of such

```
serializer_class = TestSerializer
queryset = Test.objects.all()
```

Note that the `contexts` field is not a database field. When accessing the endpoint with a GET I receive the information correctly with

```
 {
     "id": 1,
     "contexts": [{...}]
 }
```

But when sending the same data back as a POST then there's two issues. First serializer doesn't seem to be able to correlate the correct dataset since I always end up in the `create` method leading to the error

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint
```

and when printing the `data` in the create method the contexts are not present at all.

Comment: Given that you're using a `ModelViewSet`, a `POST` request would indeed try to create a new entry with `1` as the `id`. That is not possible if an entry with the id `1` already exists. To update you'll need to send a `PATCH` request to the detail route. `/api/test/1/`

Answer (score 2):

Given that you're using a `ModelViewSet` and have registered it on the url: `/api/test/`...

A `POST` request such as the one you describe would indeed try to create a new entry with `1` as the `id`. That is not possible if an entry with the `id` `1` already exists.

To update you'll need to send a `PATCH` request to the detail route. `/api/test/1/`

#### EDIT

`SerializerMethodField` is read only and won't show up in `validated_data`. You can access it in `self.context['request'].data.get('contexts')`. But I would recommend creating another serializer for the field...

```
class ContextsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = (...)

class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contexts = ContextsSerializer(many=False)
```

There is more to this if you want it done properly. Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do and why, I wouldn't want to suggest a complete solution. But you can make what ever you're trying to do work using data that hasn't been validated from the `request`.

Comment: Thanks the PATCH did the trick; however, in the `update` method the `contexts` are still not present!?